# I have bought a new mi 5 mobile

Tags: android-versions

My older phone internet was too fast. When I transferred my sim into new phone, the internet is too damn slow. It's slower than tortoise. What should I do?

Comment: You should [edit] your question and give more details. What models are your old phone and new phone? What kind of connection is it: GPRS, HSDPA, EDGE, etc?

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can suggest is to check and make sure that your phone is set to 4G (preferred) mode in Network settings.

Another thing worth considering is to check with your operator that the correct access point is being used.

And can you tell which was your previous phone? Depending on the device and its OS, it is very possible that it consumed lesser data whereas your Android's browser uses more data. Consider using Opera Mini or other browsers which compress pages before delivering to your device.

Comment: My earlier mobile was lyf flame and it's internet was very fast

Comment: Have you checked with your operator that your speed is not being throttled due to a plan issue and that your device is connecting to the 4G network?